# EF Core ToQueryString() does not include schema

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, sqldependency

I am trying to use SqlDependency, which requires a query as a string which specifies the schema (dbo.[table name]) but EF Core  ToQueryString does not include dbo.

Is there another way to get a query from Ef core  that includes the dbo keyword or a way to force SqlDependency to accept a more vague query?

Comment: Would [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-types?tabs=data-annotations) be off any use to you sir? It would require attributes being added.

Comment: Yes! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity Framework core doesn't make any assumptions as to which schema you want to use. In Sql Server, usually it'll be `dbo`, but if you don't specify it, EF will generate schema-less SQL statements. That may cause surprises when e.g. you generate a database under a user that has another default schema than `dbo`.

Lesson I learned when working with EF core:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // *Always* specify schema. Otherwise EF will generate schema-less DDL + DML.
    modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("dbo");
    ...
```

This will probably be enough for you. Yo can also specify the schema [per table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-types?tabs=data-annotations#table-schema).